# python 32 bit float conversion

Tags: python

Python 2.6 on Redhat 6.3

I have a device that saves 32 bit floating point value across 2 memory registers, split into most significant word and least significant word.
I need to convert this to a float.
I have been using the following code found on SO and it is similar to code I have seen elsewhere

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from ctypes import *
first  = sys.argv[1]
second = sys.argv[2]

reading_1 = str(hex(int(first)).lstrip("0x"))
reading_2 = str(hex(int(second)).lstrip("0x"))

sample = reading_1 + reading_2

def convert(s):
    i = int(s, 16)                   # convert from hex to a Python int
    cp = pointer(c_int(i))           # make this into a c integer
    fp = cast(cp, POINTER(c_float))  # cast the int pointer to a float pointer
    return fp.contents.value         # dereference the pointer, get the float

print convert(sample)
```

an example of the register values would be ;

register-1;16282 register-2;60597

this produces the resulting float of

1.21034872532

A perfectly cromulent number, however sometimes the memory values are something like;

register-1;16282 register-2;1147

which, using this function results in a float of;

1.46726675314e-36

which is a fantastically small number and not a number that seems to be correct. This device should be producing readings around the 1.2, 1.3 range.

What I am trying to work out is if the device is throwing bogus values or whether the values I am getting are correct but the function I am using is not properly able to convert them.

Also is there a better way to do this, like with numpy or something of that nature?
I will hold my hand up and say that I have just copied this code from examples on line and I have very little understanding of how it works, however it seemed to work in the test cases that I had available to me at the time.

Thank you.

Comment: First, are you sure you've got the endianness right (both between registers, and between the two bytes within each one)? That kind of mistake tends to give you errors like this.

Comment: I am going to admit my ignorance and ask for more information to answer your question. The device is telling me that these two values are the contents of the registers. Also the answers that I am getting, when the conversion works. Are exactly the values that I would expect, things like a voltage result of 229.26 (I'm in Ireland)

Comment: Also, I think this is a job for `struct` rather than `ctypes`: `s = struct.pack('=i', i)` then `return struct.unpack('=f', s)[0]`. That won't give you different results, but it's harder to screw up, and easier to change endianness by, e.g., throwing in a `<` in place of `=`, etc.

Comment: ah, i see, yes it would seem I am correct as otherwise I would expect to see every conversion as a number a long way outside the bounds of what I would expect, as per the comment just above, which was edited before I saw this comment from yourself.

Comment: @s.bandara: Unless he's dealing with VAX-endian or something, `reading_2 + reading_1` isn't likely to be right, but swapping the high and low of each and then doing `swapped_2 + swapped_1` might be.

Comment: The reason I asked about endianness is that register-1 has the same value both times, while register-2 has wildly different values, and you expect them to be pretty close to each other. That implies that register-2 is least-significant, not most-. And your own description implies the same. But if you run your code on a little-endian machine (like an x86), you're doing the opposite.

Comment: You should definitely use struct or bit-shifting rather than string-processing here. The reason this is going wrong is that lstrip("0x") doesn't do what you think it does. It keeps removing characters from the left of the string so long as they are either '0' or 'x'. So "0x0f07" becomes "f07" and "0x0001" becomes "1".

Comment: @Weeble, it's worse than that - `hex` doesn't generate leading zeros in the first place. `hex(1)` generates `'0x1'`, not `'0x0001'`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have the raw bytes (e.g. read from memory, from file, over the network, ...) you can use `struct` for this:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack('>f', '\x3f\x9a\xec\xb5')[0]
1.2103487253189087
```

Here, `\x3f\x9a\xec\xb5` are your input registers, 16282 (hex 0x3f9a) and 60597 (hex 0xecb5) expressed as bytes in a string. The `>` is the byte order mark.

So depending how you get the register values, you may be able to use this method (e.g. by converting your input integers to byte strings). You can use `struct` for this, too; this is your second example:

```
>>> raw = struct.pack('>HH', 16282, 1147)    # from two unsigned shorts
>>> struct.unpack('>f', raw)[0]              # to one float
1.2032617330551147
```

Comment: Moreover, `16282` and `1147` become `'\x3f\x9a\x04\x7b'` and thus unpack to `1.2032617330551147`.

Comment: Anders, thank you for the comment, how would i go about getting the register value into the format for struct?

Comment: Anders, thank you i will give that a go and see if things start to make more sense. much appreciated.

Comment: @AlanEnnis, added an example for how to do this. I split it across two lines to make it clearer but of course you can join these statements.

Comment: This looks like it did the trick. All results seem to produce a valid float after conversion. Thanks Anders. I still will admit to a massive ignorance in regards to the workings of this but I will spend some time looking into it.

Answer (score 1):

The way you've converting the two `int`s makes implicit assumptions about [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) that I believe are wrong.

So, let's back up a step. You know that the first argument is the most significant word, and the second is the least significant word. So, rather than try to figure out how to combine them into a hex string in the appropriate way, let's just do this:

```
import struct
import sys

first  = sys.argv[1]
second = sys.argv[2]

sample = int(first) << 16 | int(second)
```

Now we can just convert like this:

```
def convert(i):
    s = struct.pack('=i', i)
    return struct.unpack('=f', s)[0]
```

And if I try it on your inputs:

```
$ python floatify.py 16282 60597
1.21034872532
$ python floatify.py 16282 1147
1.20326173306
```